# Pass cv::Mat to Python from a c++ call

Tags: python, c++, opencv, python-3.8

I am running several python functions from within a c++ program using the "Python.h" library. I'm run into issues passing anything outside of standard variables to the python function. For example, the snippet to pass the value 13 you can call the function as below.

```
CPyObject pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
CPyObject var = PyLong_FromLong(13);
PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, var);
CPyObject pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
```

In order to pass an array (or in this case a cv::Mat object) I can pass the pointer by changing the var declaration as below

```
CPyObject var = PyLong_FromVoidPtr(&Mat);
```

The associated python function in both instances is as below.

```
def Function(var: int):
```

In the first instance this results in output "13", in the second a large number presumeably relating to the memory address associated with the variable Mat (as would be expected) eg; "139666632206352". What I want is a way to access the contents of the array within python. Preferably this would be by importing it directly into an appropriately formed Numpy array but any method can be made to work. The data being passed is image data which will then be processed via tensorflow in the python instance.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you try `PyLong_FromVoidPtr(Mat.data());` instead of `&Mat`?

Comment: @Roy2511 Thanks for the suggestion mate, unfortunately thats a negative, it doesn't appear to do the trick however I'm not sure how I would declare that in the python script to know for certain. It's a pointer, it has the same results as simply using the &Mat so far as I can tell.